# Cannot read property ... of undefined (property/value from context)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have an error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" from UserDetails.js. That "name" value is from context.

This is my code,

UsersContext.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios';

export const UserContext = createContext()

export function UserProvider(props) {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getNews = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
                const req = await Axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
                const data = req.data;

                setUsers(c => {
                    return [
                        ...data
                    ]
                })

                if(data.status !== "ok") throw new Error('error from api server');

            } catch (error) {
                setError(true)
            }
            setLoading(false);
        }

        getNews();
    }, [])

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{users, loading, error}}>
            {props.children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

UserDetails.js:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { UserContext } from '../contexts/UsersContext'

function UserDetails(props) {
    const {users} = useContext(UserContext)

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
                {users[0].name}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserDetails
```

{users[0].name} from UserDetail is undefined, but when im trying to use {JSON.stringify(users[0])} it has value:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Leanne Graham","username":"Bret","email":"Sincere@april.biz","address":{"street":"Kulas Light","suite":"Apt. 556","city":"Gwenborough","zipcode":"92998-3874","geo":{"lat":"-37.3159","lng":"81.1496"}},"phone":"1-770-736-8031 x56442","website":"hildegard.org","company":{"name":"Romaguera-Crona","catchPhrase":"Multi-layered client-server neural-net","bs":"harness real-time e-markets"}}
```

but why, when use JSON.stringify there has a value, but without JSON.stringify there is no value (undefined) ?

Comment: Before the axios request finishes, `users` is `[]` and `users[0]` is therefore undefined.

Comment: @ChrisG aaaaaaaaah why im forgot about that... thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because request have not return result yet and users are still [],
so to fix a problem you should do something following:

```
return loading? null : (
    <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">
            {users[0].name}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the request inside **useEffect** hook is async and didn't return any value in first render. So **users** has initail value **[]** .

Either you can use optional chaining or check loading state before showing **users** values.

```
return (
    <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">
            {users[0]?.name}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

or:

```
return loading ? null : (
    <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">
            {users[0]?.name}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

It also better to handle the case in which **name** property is an empty string with **||** operator:

```
return loading ? null : (
    <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">
            {users[0]?.name || "Anonymous"}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

During the 3 seconds it takes for this `apiRequest` to return a value your Javascript code is trying to compile as quickly as possible.

If you don't account for the 3 seconds in which `readUsers` is `undefined` you will get an error.

This is because `readUsers` is initialised to the special value `undefined` which has no methods or values that are accessible from it.

If you open up your console and try typing `undefined[0]` or `undefined.toString()` you will get an error because nothing exists on `undefined`.

To avoid the error you should provide a fallback so when a value is `undefined` do this and then once it becomes a different value that has methods and values that are accessible from it allow them to execute.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const oneSecond = 1000;
const threeSeconds = 3 * oneSecond;

// -> Fake API request
function apiRequest() {
  // -> Create a new Promise
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    // -> Resolve the Promise after waiting three seconds
    setTimeout(() => resolve([{ name: "Bill" }]), threeSeconds)
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [readUsers, writeUsers] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    // -> Make request (which takes 3 seconds), then update state
    apiRequest().then((users) => writeUsers(users));
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {readUsers ? (
        readUsers.map((user) => <div>{user.name}</div>)
      ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```